# Rigid Motions uniquely specified by triangles?

Tags: geometry, rigid-transformation

I'm currently reading the all-familiar *"Concepts of Modern Mathematics"* by Ian Stewart. At some point in his chapter on motion geometry, Stewart states:

> "It is a consequence of the two-dimensionality of the plane that any
>   rigid motion is uniquely specified by what it does to a
>   (non-degenerate) triangle, whence it is sufficient to consider only
>   triangles."

He follows this up with a note under the *"Notes"* section, saying:

> This statement should perhaps be expanded. Given three points A, B, C (distinct and non-collinear) and three distances a, b, c, there is at most one point distance a from A, distance b from B and c from C. Since rigid motions do not change distances, it follows that once we know what happens to a triangle we know what happens to everything else.

Why? Doesn't a simple line segment between two points suffice to both demonstrate and specify what happens when the three basic rigid motions of translation, rotation and reflection are applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line segment is not enough to distinguish the identity transformation from a reflection over the line containing the segment.

Adding a third point not collinear with the endpoints of the line segment allows you to distinguish between the two.

Comment: Yes, but couldn't the same be said of multiple transformations compounded in such a way that distinguishing that transformation from a simple translation isn't possible? And why triangles - surely this holds for rectangles too? Or circles?

Comment: *Why triangles* The only thing special about a triangle is that you get three noncollinear points. A rectangle or circle could do it as well, it's just that a triangle is sort of optimum.

Comment: *couldn't the same be said ... in such a way* I don't understand what you're getting at. The compound transformation will be uniquely determined by what it does on three noncollinear points. If you have an example you want to ask about, maybe that will help.

Comment: You said *A line segment is not enough to distinguish the identity transformation from a reflection over the line containing the segment.* So if distinguishing transformations is a criterion, a triangle wouldn't suffice to distinguish the identity transformation from a couple of transformations applied in such a way that the triangle ends up like it started before the transformations. And what's so special about having three noncollinear points? Doesn't a circle have that property too?

Comment: @Luke You're making too much of sequences of transformations. There is no claim here that three points distinguishes the result of sequences of transformations, and indeed that is absurd. There is only the initial position of the points and the final position of the points

Comment: @Luke *Doesnt a circle have that property?* yes, and a rectangle. That was my point.

Comment: Alright, it just seemed odd that the author would so emphatically mention triangles as the way in which transformations are specified.

Comment: @Luke why choose something more complicated?

Comment: I see what you are saying @rschwieb. Can you explain the proof a little further? I get that, as you say, a line segment wouldn't suffice; a single point obviously doesn't cause everything would just be a shift... But why are 3 points enough? I don't follow the proof in the book.

Comment: @JamesBender Each point is uniquely determined by its distances to the vertices of the triangle.  Since a rigid motion preserves these distances, the rigid motion *must* map a point to the new point with the same relative distances from the mapped triangle’s vertices .